# Type Mismatch Error Code other than 13

Tags: windows

Is it possible to receive an error code other than 13 (e.g. 0) for a type mismatch error?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is probably a VB error and I also believe that run-time error 13 is a 'type mismatch' error.. period. There isn't more than one kind of 'type mismatch' error. Run-time error 7 for example is an 'out of memory' error.

Comment: Thanks.  I suspected as such since a "0" error code (aka return code) in most languages means everything is "OK." But not being a VB developer (just someone trying to assist), I had to ask.